# How to deploy Angular 4 app to apache htdocs?

Tags: apache, angular, htdocs

Hi i would like to know how to deploy Angular 4 app to apache's htdocs. I tried copying the whole content of the project and do ng --build but still not working, please help Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use this command

```
ng build --base-href .
```

& Then copy the dist

Comment: how to deploy it to ngnix docker app ?